EFATO after V2 during initial climb AP already on
I am seeing procedures for EFATO after V1 which means that Take off with single engine and handling situation before AP is on. What if engine failure happens just after takeoff, between take off and initial climb with AP already on, flaps cleaned to zero but still climbing at green dot speed below 10000 ft?

There are procedures for each of those situations, what is your question? V1 is the maximum speed at which takeoff can be aborted. Vr is the speed at which the pilot actively starts the liftoff process and V2 is the speed at which a safe climb-out can be maintained with one engine inoperative.

Hi, unsure what is unclear. I'd like to know the procedure for an engine failure happening after v2. in initial climb stage towards FL 10 000Ft (so we are below 10000) AP already  on.also specified that already accelerating i.e after thrust red/ acc and speed towards s speed. Ideally procedure if no engine damage and the with engine damage. @bianfable any help or documentation link?

The autopilot will handle engine failures. If ATHR is on, put the thrust levers into MCT gate. Once the flight path is stabilised apply the engine failure procedure as described by the ECAM.
